# Is it safe to use lvresize -r to reduce LVM

Tags: filesystems, lvm

I know I can increase the size of file system and LV in one go using `lvresize -r` but is it safe to use the sam approach to reduce a LV file system ?

here is the man page of `-r`

```
-r, --resizefs
    Resize underlying file system together with the logical volume using fsadm(8).
```

I would thought it should be safe if file system gets reduce first.

Thanks

Comment: i'm having the same problem. Did you find any solution ? Bernd

Comment: @Bernd Hi there, I did some testing myself, resize2fs is called before the LV is reduced but there is a minimum requirement, if the new size is less than minimum, the resize will just fail.

Answer (score 0):

From [XFS FAQ](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_Is_there_a_way_to_make_a_XFS_filesystem_larger_or_smaller.3F), [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/540013) and [CentOS QA](https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=56784):

You **can't** shrink xfs.

The only way to do this is to backup your data, create another smaller LV.